# ScrollView dose't moves using scrollTo() horizontally

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have the following horizontal scrollView and I would like to scroll to X position.

```
 <ScrollView horizontal={true} ref={ref => this.scrollView = ref} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>

                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.onPressDate(I18n.t("month1"))}} style={styles.month}>
                      <View style={{alignSelf: 'center' }}>
                        <Text style={[commonStyle.normalItemBold,{color:this.state.underlineMonth1?'#000':'#9B9B9B'}]}>{I18n.t("month1")}</Text>
                        <View  style={[styles.rowSep, {opacity: this.state.underlineMonth1?100:0} ]}/>
                      </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.onPressDate(I18n.t("month2"))}} style={styles.month}>
                      <View   style={{alignSelf: 'center' }}>
                        <Text style={[commonStyle.normalItemBold,{color:this.state.underlineMonth2?'#000':'#9B9B9B'}]}>{I18n.t("month2")}</Text>
                        <View  style={[styles.rowSep, {opacity: this.state.underlineMonth2?100:0} ]}/>
                      </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.onPressDate(I18n.t("month3"))}} style={styles.month}>
                      <View   style={{alignSelf: 'center' }}>
                        <Text style={[commonStyle.normalItemBold,{color:this.state.underlineMonth3?'#000':'#9B9B9B'}]}>{I18n.t("month3")}</Text>
                        <View  style={[styles.rowSep, {opacity: this.state.underlineMonth3?100:0} ]}/>
                      </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.onPressDate(I18n.t("month4"))}} style={styles.month}>
                      <View   style={{alignSelf: 'center' }}>
                        <Text style={[commonStyle.normalItemBold,{color:this.state.underlineMonth4?'#000':'#9B9B9B'}]}>{I18n.t("month4")}</Text>
                        <View  style={[styles.rowSep, {opacity: this.state.underlineMonth4?100:0} ]}/>
                      </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.onPressDate(I18n.t("month5"))}} style={styles.month}>
                      <View   style={{alignSelf: 'center' }}>
                        <Text style={[commonStyle.normalItemBold,{color:this.state.underlineMonth5?'#000':'#9B9B9B'}]}>{I18n.t("month5")}</Text>
                        <View  style={[styles.rowSep, {opacity: this.state.underlineMonth5?100:0} ]}/>
                      </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                  </ScrollView>
```

I used scrollTo in the ComponentDidMount() but it did't work and the scrollView dose't come up with the moved position. Here is the code:

```
componentDidMount=()=>{

   this.scrollView.scrollTo({  X:0, Y:100 });
}
```

Can you help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrolling to a position can be achieved by using the `scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0, animated: true})` method.

Just set a x: value for horizontal scrolling or y: value for vertical.

In your case it should be:

```
scrollTo({x: 100, y: 0, animated: true})
```